# How do we detect if a shadow root was made with v0 or v1 API?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, shadow-dom

Suppose a JS module exports `shadowRoot` which was created with either `el.createShadowRoot` or `el.attachShadow` (we don't know which). How do we detect if the root is a v0 shadow root or a v1 shadow root (i.e. how do we detect which method was used to create the root)?

f.e., What would I fill in the following conditional statements?

```
// for argument's sake, we don't create the root, we only get a reference
// to it:
import shadowRoot from 'somewhere'

function getShadowRootVersion(root) {
    if ( ... )
        return 'v0'

    if ( ... )
        return 'v1'
}

console.log(getShadowRootVersion(shadowRoot)) // should output "v0" or "v1".
```

**More info:**

We want to find out if a shadow root was created from `createShadowRoot` or from `attachShadow`. The resulting roots are different: in the root created with `createShadowRoot`, `<content>` elements are used for distributing elements. In roots created with `attachShadow`, `<content>` elements don't do anything, and `<slot>` elements are used instead. How do we detect which method was used to create a root (i.e. whether we have a v0 root or a v1 root)?

Comment: You should add this information to the question.  

"We want to find out if a root was create from createShadowRoot or from attachShadow. The resulting roots are different. In the root created with createShadowRoot, <content> elements are used to distribute elements. In roots created with attachShadow, <content> elements don't do anything, and <slot> elements have to be used. How do we detect which method was used to create a root?" - It better clarifies what you actually want so people don't make wrong assumptions and get downvoted for them.

Comment: @nixkuroi Sorry for the downvote. I will add that. Thanks!!

Comment: Generally one would use feature detection rather than version detection as it should be more helpful...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's easy to detect features (f.e. if `attachShadow` method exists), but what I need is to detect if a root was made with one method or the other (the resulting roots have differences). This isn't feature detection, it's detection of one type of instance vs the other. Assume both v0 and v1 API exists (which is the case in the latest Chrome).

Comment: Why the downvote? I've updated the question, maybe now it has enough info?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Also, Chrome has both "features" (v0 and v1 shadow roots), so detecting both features isn't so helpful. I want to specifically detect which version a shadow root is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went a similar direction to Hayato Ito's answer. However, instead of creating `slot` elements, I target `content` elements. I was not able to find a way to detect the version off of any API method detection.

I targeted `content` elements since content elements do not natively have events for them, unlike `slotchange` on the `slot` event, which hopefully could lead to a small performance boost. Plus the function returns `v1` a little faster if the browser does not support `v0` at all.

```
function shadowType(shadowRoot) {
    if (!shadowRoot) {
        // closed shadow dom does not appear to have a shadowRoot...
        // It could be assumed that it is v1, but for now return undefined
        return;
    }

    const content = document.createElement('content');
    // In browsers that support v1, but not v0 (ex: Safari)
    if (!content.getDistributedNodes) {
        return 'v1';
    }

    content.setAttribute('select', 'test-shadow-dom-version');
    shadowRoot.appendChild(content);

    const testElement = document.createElement('test-shadow-dom-version');
    shadowRoot.host.appendChild(testElement);
    const type = (content.getDistributedNodes().length) ? 'v0' : 'v1';
    shadowRoot.removeChild(content);
    shadowRoot.host.removeChild(testElement);

    return type;
}
```

It definitely feels like a "hack", because of need to append random dom :(. I did test this in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE11, and Edge. I tested components made using the webcomponentsjs (v0) polyfill, and it correctly returned `v0` for each component. I also tested those same browsers with just the shadydom (v1) polyfill with components created with the v1 spec, and received `v1` in all of those browsers.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks KevBot!

Answer (score 1):

The following hack should work:

```
function isV1(shadowRoot) {
  const slot = document.createElement('slot');
  shadowRoot.appendChild(slot);
  slot.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  const assignedNodes = slot.assignedNodes({ flatten: true });
  slot.remove();
  return assignedNodes.length !== 0;
}
```

IMO, there is something wrong when you have to detect it.

Comment: Thanks Hayato! A downside of this is the runtime cost of creating elements and triggering distribution just to get the result. I agree that there's something wrong if *app code* is doing this, but I'm making a library that should just work (user can use v0 or v1 shadows). The Custom Elements of my library will render to WebGL rather than with the HTML engine, so if my library will support ShadowDOM, then (I think) it needs to detect the flat tree in order to render things properly.

Comment: A-Frame (http://aframe.io) will face the same problem if they wish to be ShadowDOM-compatible (currently it is not). For example, here's the Hello World A-Frame example, with no ShadowDOM: https://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/1ecfha5h, and here's the same example showing one way to use ShadowDOM, but it fails to work: https://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/1ecfha5h/1.

Comment: Will this method cause any forced layout, rendering, or any other undesired side effects?

Comment: you said "IMO, there is something wrong when you have to detect it.", but it is because I want my library to work in either environment, not that I'm mixing the versions of ShadowDOM in my app.

Comment: This method should not cause any forced layout, at least in Blink.

Comment: I had to deselect this as the answer for now, because I have a case where sometimes it returns true, sometimes false, on the same v1 shadow root instance.