# How do we observe distribution changes on a v0 shadow root?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

In v1 shadow roots, we can listen to `slotchange` on `<slot>` elements then use `slot.assignedNodes()` to detect changes. I am looking for a way to do it with v0 shadow roots.

With ShadowDOM v0, is there a way to observe changes in distributed nodes of a `<content>` element in a shadow root?

The easiest way to implement this would be by using `requestAnimationFrame` to create a poll loop that calls `content.getDistributedNodes()` to compare new results with old results, but obviously polling is not ideal and is expensive.

How can it be done?

Comment: Could you use a mutation observer on the `content` element?

Comment: @KevBot How would I do that? `childList` observes children, but what about distributed nodes? Got an example?

Comment: Might be possible using the [`.getDistributedNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLContentElement/getDistributedNodes) method, and from there, a mutation observer could be called on those elements. Or possibly attaching a mutation observer on the insertion points [`.getDestinationInsertionPoints()`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-getDestinationInsertionPoints). I will try to work something more concrete up in the morning.

Comment: Any context to why this was down-voted?

Comment: @KevBot, I thought about it a little: for a given content element that we wish to observe, we can traverse up from it to find the shadow root host, then use MutationObserver on the host to detect changes in children, and whenever that happens we just call `.getDistributedNodes` on the content element to find the new distribution. We would also need to use MutationObserver on all the host children to detect attribute changes, since those can cause the selector results of the root's `<content>` element to change.

Comment: Also curious to know why downvoted.

Comment: Is changes for text nodes (`characterData`) something that needs to be watched for in the mutation observer? Or would you just be looking for attribute changes, and the addition or deletion of nodes?

Comment: Yep, text nodes can be distributed to default content element when the content element does not have a selector. But if there is a selector, then in that case text nodes cannot be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a need for this exact thing about the same time you did. I ended up creating a library for this which I have been using for a week or so now in testing. The library is called [content-change](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/content-change). It's working well for me, but I'm sure there are plenty of opportunities for improvement.

It works like this; similarly to the `slot` element's `slotchange` event from Shadow DOM v1:

```
// Because this is non-spec, specify internally which components get to be watched
// "this" is the host element
ContentChange.watch(this);

const contentElement = shadow.querySelector('someContentSelector');
contentElement.addEventListener('contentchange', e => {
    // React to distributed node changes for this content element
});
```

The `event` returned to the listener contains a few different types in the `event.details`. The `event.details.type` will be one of the three:

- `"nodesAdded"`
- `"nodesRemoved"`
- `"mutation"`

allowing you to react to different scenarios. For example, when nodes added to the host element fulfill the requirement to be distributed to that content element, you will receive the following:

```
{
    "type": "nodesAdded",
    "nodesAdded": [Nodes] // An array of newly distributed nodes
}
```

Comment: Cool! Nice implementation. I was thinking along those lines too, using MutationObserver on the host, but then for the part of my implementation that would've been equivalent to your `discoverAddedAndRemovedNodes` I was thinking to run the query associated with the `<content>` elements to discover which elements in the host matched, but your approach using `getDistributedNodes` is simply cleaner. I.e., you're using `getDistributedNodes` on MutationObserver changes unlike in my original post where I thought about using `getDistributedNodes ` inside an animation frame poll loop.

Comment: By the way, any thoughts on the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004064 I think it would be nice because I'd like to observer distribution changes on a host, but I am not creating the hosts so I don't know if they use v0 or v1 slots. Once I detect that, I can use your content-change lib on the v0 roots. :D

Comment: @trusktr Yeah, I actually headed down the path of trying to figure out which elements could be distributed from the host with all the rules from the content elements. But what ended up happening is that if a content element is not using a selector, or has `*` as the selector, then it distributes textNodes (as you already know). Those textNodes were really difficult to work with. Anyways, I will take a look at that other question, looks very interesting.

Comment: Thanks for that other answer. Works awesome. I'm going to try your lib soon. :D

Comment: @trusktr, you're welcome. Glad that worked out for you.