# How to observe distribution changes on ShadowDOM v1 slots?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

(This is not a duplicate of [How do we observe distribution changes on a v0 shadow root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880512/how-do-we-observe-distribution-changes-on-a-v0-shadow-root/41269275), because that question is for ShadowDOM v0, and the mention it gives regarding slots and slotchange events for ShadowDOM v1 is incomplete)

The problem is, a `slotchange` event tells you when nodes or elements were distributed *through* a slot, but it does not necessarily tell you the *final* distribution of nodes or elements. If you have a slot assigned to a slot assigned to a slot (hence you have a hierarchy of three ShadowRoot trees), a `slotchange` event will fire on all three slots due to event bubbling, and the bubble order will be from the ancestor slots to the descendant-most slot, meaning that the deepest slot will be the last to fire an event. THe order is opposite if using the event `capture` phase. During event propagation, `event.target` will always be the slot of the ancestor-most shadow tree, which means that `event.target` is *not* the slot at which nodes or elements are finally distributed to.

**Question:** What is not immediately obvious, is how do we detect the final distribution of nodes or elements using slotchange events (because there are no other events like a hypothetical `distribution` event which would be simple and helpful)?

What we don't have is a single non-bubbling event like `distributionchange` that would fire on a slot *if and only if* nodes or elements are finally distributed (or undistributed) to (or from) that slot. We also don't have a method like `slot.distributedNodes()` or `slot.distributedElements()` which would hypothetically tell us this information in our non-bubbling `distributionchange` event handlers.

Comment: Just to clarify: when you say *a slot assigned to a slot assigned to a slot*, you mean three web components each with its own Shadow DOM and slots?

Comment: Doesn't [event.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) give you the correct "target"?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, for example. But you could achieve the same thing by also just adding three shadow roots on a branch of DOM elements without using custom elements.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That will give you a path where the first array item is the ancestor-most slot (not the slot where elements are finally distributed to) and the last item is Window. After this, you would need to run logic on the array to find the last-most slot in the array in order to find the slot where elements are finally distributed to. So yeah, you could use that information, but it wouldn't be ideal. Also is there any overhead from getting the composed path?

Answer (score 0):

Although not immediately obvious like a `distributionchange` event paired with `distributedNodes` or `distributeElements` APIs would be, the answer is actually fairly simple once some details involved with `slotchange` and `distributedNode` or `distributeElements` are understood:

```js
someSlot.addEventListener('slotchange', event => {
  // Always use `event.currentTarget` because that points to the slot
  // that this event handler is on, whereas `event.target` will
  // always point to the slot from the ancestor-most shadow tree.
  // That ancestor-most tree's slot is slotted to this slot (currentTarget)
  // or to some other slot that is ultimately distributed to this slot.
  const slot = event.currentTarget

  // If the slot has an assignedSlot, then it can not possibly be the slot
  // where nodes or elements are finally distributed to, so return an empty
  // array in that case. Otherwise, the slot must be the final distribution
  // slot, in which case calling assignedNodes with flatten:true will give
  // the desired result (the finally-distributed nodes).
  const distributedNodes = slot.assignedSlot ? [] : slot.assignedNodes({flatten: true})

  // Similar if you just want elements (f.e. not text nodes):
  const distributedElements = slot.assignedSlot ? [] : slot.assignedElements({flatten: true})
})
```

If you have the tree hierarchy `document > shadowtree1 > shadowtree2 > shadowtree3`, where `shadowtree1` has a slot `A` that is slotted (assigned) to slot `B` in `shadowtree2`, where slot `B` is slotted to slot `C` in `shadowtree3`, then if elements `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in `document` are slotted to slot `A`, and if you have this event handler on each of those three slots, then the result of `distributedElements` for each of the slots will be:

- A: []
- B: []
- C: [foo, bar, baz]

Had we not checked for `assignedSlot` and only used `assignedElements({flatten: true})`, the result would be the following which would not tell us which slot actually represents where the elements are distributed to:

- A: [foo, bar, baz]
- B: [foo, bar, baz]
- C: [foo, bar, baz]

Because then we wouldn't know which slot is actually the one that the elements are distributed to.

If slot `C` were to be removed from `shadowtree3`, then the events would fire again, and the result would be:

- A: []
- B: [foo, bar, baz]

Using this knowledge, we can make a polyfill for `distributionchange` and `distributedElements()` APIs...

Comment: Better posted and discussed in the WICG forums. I don't think you get the views or even responses here.

Comment: You got [an answer on WICG](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/933).

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I opened a new suggestion there: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/940