# How to detect which version of shadowDOM does a shadowRoot use

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

So I have two shadowRoot nodes

- one created via `createShadowRoot()` - v0
- another created via `attachShadow()` - v1

Now, if I look at properties and __proto__ of these both nodes - there's no visible difference. How do I tell by which version was that shadowRoot created? I'm making a third-party service which mirrors the content of a given page, which means I have to create right version of shadowDOM in the mirror page in order to know whether `<content>` or `<slot>` elements are going to be used (they may get inserted in dynamically).

Comment: it's not possible because whatever method is called a same native shadow dom is added

Comment: @Supersharp it's not exactly the same. Because `<content>` doesn't work in shadow DOM v1 and `<slot>` does not in v0. And it's possible to create both versions within the same document (as of Chrome 64)

Comment: I mean the brower knows how the shadow DOM was created (then it will react accordingly to slot or content tags), but this is not exposed to the userland.

Comment: Maybe this post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40004064/4600982

Comment: Well, looks my question is a duplicate. The chosen answer there is actually the direction I went to solve my problem, but as some sites have over 100 shadowrooted elements I don't like the prospect of performance loss bc of nodes shoveling.. But well, another compromise I guess